# Why is data loading on component only after first render in react-native

Tags: react-native

I dont know how explain this problem, but maybe someone know. Right now i learning React-native and find some problem.

If i open some component first time, i dont see any data, but if i do this second time data loaded.

```
class Followers extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const {uid} = this.props.user;
    this.props.followersFetch({uid});
    this.createDataSource(this.props)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps)
  }
  createDataSource({followersList}) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    })
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(followersList)
  }

  renderRow(follower) {
    return (<User follower={follower}/>);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <ListView enableEmptySections dataSource={this.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow}/>
        </Content>
      </Container>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
  const {followersList} = state.relation;
  const {uid} = state.profile;
  return {uid, followersList}

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {followersFetch})(Followers);


I'm trying use ComponentDidMount for sure data is loading but it give me error
```

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that followersFetch function is asychronous and takes longer than you'd want so data arrive after this component mounts-renders. I would suggest fetching the data earlier on.

Comment: Best way is to show activity indicator till whole data loaded in objects and then render required component using setState.